# The scheme of intersection points of algebraic plane curves defined over a number field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

This question concerns two related but different notions of "plane curves", where we consider both curves in the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$ and the affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2$.

Given two plane curves $C_1, C_2$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ defined over a number field $K$, consider the 0-dimensional scheme given by $C_1 \cap C_2$. By Bezout's theorem, the cardinality of $(C_1 \cap C_2)(\overline{K})$ is equal to $mn$, where $m,n$ are the degrees of $C_1, C_2$ respectively. Thus the absolute Galois group $\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ acts on $(C_1 \cap C_2)(\overline{K})$.

Is there a simple way to determine whether this action is transitive, given the coefficients of $C_1, C_2$?

One can formulate the same question for pairs of curves in $\mathbb{A}^2$.

The specific case I am interested in is this: suppose we are given two polynomials (in the case I care about one can assume further that they are homogeneous) $f,g \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ of degrees $m,n$ respectively, define the curves $C_f(a), C_g(b)$ determined by the equations $f(x,y) = a, g(x,y) = b$ respectively. What conditions can we impose on $a,b$ (the coefficients of $f,g$ considered to be fixed) such that the action of $\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ on $(C_f(a) \cap C_g(b))(\overline{K})$ is transitive?

Comment: This should come down to Hilbert Irreducibility, but I can't see an easy way to say anything in terms of $a$ and $b$. For example, in the easiest case when $g = y$, you are asking, given a fixed polymonial $f(x)$, for which $a$ is $f(x) - a$ irreducible? If $f$ is irreducible, Hilbert Irreducibility tells you $f - a$ is irreducible for a Zariski-dense set of $a$, but characterizing which $a$ depends entirely on $f$.

Comment: Sorry, $f - a$ is always irreducible for a Zariski-dense set of $a$ (it's linear as a polynomial in $a$, so is irreducible in $\mathbb Q(x,a)$).  But the point still stands, unless you're happy with something as non-specific as "it's true for Zariski-dense $a$ and $b$"

Comment: This is not what Bézout's theorem says: Consider the projectivisations of the curves $y = x^2$ and $y = 0$.

In any case, your condition that the Galois action of $(C_1 \cap C_2)(\bar{K})$ is transitive is equivalent to $C_1 \cap C_2$ being an irreducible scheme over $K$. Standard computation algebra systems like Magma can tell you whether a given scheme is irreducible in any given case.